# How to put multiple fields value of a record into one field of another record

Tags: trigger

Say object 1

Business Group Name = Akamai

Account = Collection (Lookup)

BG1 = 1

BG2 = 2

BG3 = 3

into another objects

object 2
Account Name = Collection

BG Data = 1-2-3

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, salesforce standard features can't implement this and you can use trigger to update object 2 when the value of object1 is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Are those object related? You could use a formula field in that case, in other case as Allen said you can go for a trigger or even you can use a process builder that launch a flow and do it inside it.